# How to add AuthKey plugin to Geoserver (localhost:8600)

Tags: docker, plugins, geoserver

I am running Geoserver using Docker.

https://github.com/camptocamp/docker-geoserver

How to add the AuthKey Plugin (as you can see on the image below)?

[image: Authentication filter image]

I have already downloaded zip-file.

The question would be where to extract files from there?

Answer (score 0):

As with any other GeoServer extension you need to unpack the files into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder and restart GeoServer.